# XHR failed loading : mobile browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, xmlhttprequest, navigator

I am doing a simple ajax request with a file inside it, it looks like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/web/shop',
    data: data,
    error: (error) => {
        console.log("Ajax request error :", error);
        leyaMDC['form'].querySelector('#btnSub').innerHTML = "Envoyer";
        leyaMDC['form'].querySelector('#btnSub').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("load_div").style = "display: none";
        return false;
    }
}).done(function(jsonRes) {
```

This works on desktop chrome and safari, but each time I try it on mobile phone, I get this error (from chrome://inspect)

```
jquery.min.js:formatted:3954 XHR failed loading: POST "https://agent-appbot-dev.xxxxxx.com/web/shop".
jquery.min.js:formatted:3954 POST https://agent-appbot-dev.xxxxx.com/web/shop 500
send    @   jquery.min.js:formatted:3954
ajax
```

Is there any restriction about ajax post body size ? or do you have some ideas that I could try ? 
Thank you !
I tried the dataType and contentType things but it doesn't do any better thing